# recycler view library versions compatible with compiled sdk version 24

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having problems in adjusting my recycler view library version with the compiled SDK version as says error.

my code is as follows:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.users.recyclerviewreloaded"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error in your SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion

`compileSdkVersion 25 and buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`